# When starting new django process during testing it uses the wrong database

Tags: django, database, multiprocessing

If I start a new process in a django test case, it uses the normal database instead of the testing database.

```
class ClientManagerTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.clientprocess = Process(target=run).start()
```

Now If I do e.g.

```
def run():
   User.objects.all()
```

it queries the standard database instead of the testing database. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the behavior you're seeing, you'd need to use a callable further up the stack that will initialize Django's test infrastructure appropriately.

However, that's not a recommended way to handle sharing work across processes in Django. You should consider using [the `celery` library](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/); they provide [unit testing documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/django-celery/en/2.4/cookbook/unit-testing.html) for this use case.